# PHP submit button whenever user clicks

Tags: php, html, form-submit

I will like to get multiple request after clicking submit. Meaning that after i clicked submit and get the result, i will like to inquire results again and click submit again. I don't want to lead myself back to nothingness.

```
 <?php
 error_reporting(0);
 if (!$_POST['submit'])
 {
 <form action="http://localhost/test.php" method="post">
 Type of Leave: 
 <select name="leave">
 <option value=""selected="selected"></option>
 <option VALUE="Medical Leave"> Medical Leave</option>
 <option VALUE="Unpaid Leave"> Unpaid Leave</option> 
 </select>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check!" />
 </form>
 <?php
 }
 else
 {
 $conn=odbc_connect("employee","","") or die (odbc_errormsg());
 if (!$conn)  
 {
 exit
 ("Connection Failed: " . $conn);
 }
 else
 {
 $choice = $_POST['leave'];
 $sql="SELECT * FROM balance WHERE ID=$username";
 $rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
 ?>
 <?php
 while (odbc_fetch_row($rs))
 {
 $choice=odbc_result($rs,"$choice");
 echo "<tr><td>$choice</td>";
 }
 odbc_close($conn);
 echo "</table>";
 }
 }
```

Currently the code itself queries out the expected output that I want, but the only downside is it stays there as an output. What my aim is to have the submit and the select choice option stays there so that I can continue to output the result I want, thanks.

Comment: So When the form is submitted, you want both the results table as well as the form to show?

Comment: Why are you turning `error_reporting` off?

Comment: @JMC I have it done. What i want is after the form and result is shown, i have the capability to choose another time. For example, 1st time i query Medical Leave. Medical leave results are shown. So i click column for Unpaid Leave and click submit, it will show out Unpaid Leave result. @ Jack, because I will have the notice error of "submit"

Comment: @user, please make sure you turn error reporting back on when this goes on a live server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best user experience would be to use AJAX to dynamically change the results table depending on what is chosen in the dropdown. For a simpler solution, you could try moving the form up and out of the if/else loop. Put the form first, then after the form prints, check for `if ($_POST['submit'])`.

In this example, I also added a little function to add `selected="selected"` to whichever option was chosen for this submit. It's very rough, but you get the idea.

```
<?php
function matchPost($name,$val) {
if($val == $name)
    echo 'selected="selected"';
}
?>

<form action="http://localhost/test.php" method="post">
 Type of Leave: 
 <select name="leave">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option <?php matchPost('Medical_Leave',$_POST['leave']); ?> VALUE="Medical_Leave"> Medical Leave</option>
 <option <?php matchPost('Unpaid_Leave',$_POST['leave']); ?> VALUE="Unpaid_Leave"> Unpaid Leave</option> 
 </select>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check!" />
 </form>

<?php
 if ($_POST['submit'])

 {
 $conn=odbc_connect("employee","","") or die (odbc_errormsg());
 if (!$conn)  
 {
 exit
 ("Connection Failed: " . $conn);
 }
 else
 {
 $choice = $_POST['leave'];
 $sql="SELECT * FROM balance WHERE ID=$username";
 $rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
 ?>
 <?php
 while (odbc_fetch_row($rs))
 {
 $choice=odbc_result($rs,"$choice");
 echo "<tr><td>$choice</td>";
 }
 odbc_close($conn);
 echo "</table>";
 }
 }
```